# Unable to connect third screen, does my laptop even support it?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3537. It has one hdmi port and no vga, dvi or display port. I already have one screen connected through the HDMI port. From what I have seen on the internet, I could connect the third screen through the USB 3.0 port. I bought a USB 3.0 to VGA cable but the screen isn't turning on. I have a built in Radeon graphics card. Windows 7. i5.

For info, the screen works fine through the hdmi port. So the problem lies definitely with my laptop.

Is it possible my laptop doenst have the capability to output on three different screens? I used Intel manager to install the latest Intel driver but it said my system does not have the minimum requirements to install this driver.

Comment: What cable did you buy? USB doesn't send video signals, it allows devices to be connected which MAY include a video device of some sort. GPUs often have a limit to the total number of pixels they can push. Most USB-based graphics adapters (such as DisplayLink devices) act as a psuedo graphics card, basically giving you another GPU to run the extra screen, getting around this. However, your computer is old, and it is very possible the OS does not support the drivers of the device.

Comment: @music2myear I bought the USB3.0 to VGA cable that specifically says on the cover that it can be used to connect an extra monitor through the USB port.

Comment: Does it state it works with Windows 7?

Comment: @music2myear Yes. WinXP-Win10

Comment: What model is the cable?

Comment: Also, when it automatically detects the USB, it says USB driver installed but Video not. So it detects it as a simple USB not as a USB connected to a video output,

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B079212ZV2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: First issue seems to be getting your cable to work, not to get all the three monitors to work. Please confirm whether it works if your HDMI monitor is disconnected.

Comment: not working :/ It detects the display. I can drag windows to that screen but nothing displays.

Comment: That sounds as though your screen isn't functioning properly. If you cup your hands over the screen and move something around on it, do you see faint images?

Comment: @music2myear Now that I have tested them again, the screen isn't working with the hdmi port as well. Also, my cable isn't working for both screens. Basically screen 1 works only through hdmi port and screen 2 doesn't work with any port and keeps showing check signal cable message. Now i'm really confused.

Comment: You may have two problems: 1) Screen 2 is bad. 2) The USB-to-VGA device you purchased doesn't work.

Comment: @music2myear The cable works. I forgot to install the driver that came with it. It seems my second screen is bad.

Comment: Go ahead and write that up as the solution and mark it as such. That will help people going forward in the future.

Comment: @music2myear I posted the solution as an answer. The screen wasn't bad. I just had to switch the source. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was doing a few things wrong.

1. I bought [this cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B079212ZV2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to connect the third screen. It came with a small CD which I had to install to get the cable working.
2. The third screen I was using wasn't really bad. It was just switched to some other form of input. I had to change the source to analog and it started working.

So now I have one screen connected through the HDMI port and one screen connected through the USB3.0 port using a USB3.0 to VGA converter. Everything is working fine, though I cannot change the resolution on the third screen. That is not important for me at the moment.